# Node: check `boolean` value from defined `model`

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to update position in my todo list

```
var Todo = mongoose.model('Todo', {         
text : String,
done : Boolean
});
```

`database` mode has two `elements`, and I want to update only `boolean` - done.

```
      app.put('/api/todos/:todo_id', function(req, res) {
      var query = { _id: req.params.todo_id }; 
            Todo.update(query,
                { done: true
                 }, function(err, todo) {
                    if (err)
                            res.send(err);
                    Todo.find(function(err, todos) {
                            if (err)
                                    res.send(err)
                            res.json(todos);
                    });
            });
    });
```

I would like to check actual value and then update. Done is from `mongoose` `model` so I can't check it like that?

```
if (done != true){
done: true }
 else {
done: false }
```

Is something like that possible?

Comment: Why not `done: !done` if you're simply inverting it? You can't slam an `if` inside the middle of an object initializer.

Comment: You should use this `Todo.update(query,{ $set: { done: true }}, ...`, What is the point for checking the done property? I mean if a user mark the todo as done then just save it to db no matter what its previous value was.

Comment: done: !done - doesn't work :/ 
i want to check this cause my task is switch so if I change mind I can switch this task to do it again

Answer (score 1):

```
app.put('/api/todos/:todo_id', function(req, res) {
    Todo.findById(req.params.todo_id, function(err, todo) { // get todo by Model.findById
        if (err) return res.send(err);
        todo.done = !todo.done;                             // toggle todo's done field
        todo.save(function(err) {                           // save to database
            if (err) return res.send(err);
            res.json(todo);                                 // return the saved todo
        });
});
```

Comment: that case i need to refresh page every change to see effect :p

Comment: you must receive data from `res.json(todo);` on front-end and update your todo list by yourself, cuz you using `res.json`

Comment: okey, but my code above works for example where I have task undone - and it sets task done (true) without refreshing